# Can I overwrite a statement if autocommit is disabled?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

Lets say I do have code like this:

```
let connection;
let preparedStatement;

connection = createConnectionSomehow();
connection.setAutoCommit(false);

preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query1);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query2);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

connection.commit();
```

Will both queries been executed or will the second query overwrite the first one?

Comment: Give it a try and you will definitely know the answer.

Comment: The four lines in the middle are equivalent to `connection.prepareStatement(query1).executeUpdate(); connection.prepareStatement(query2).executeUpdate();`. You don’t seem to need `preparedStatement` at all.

Comment: *Will both queries been executed or will the second query overwrite the first one?* AutoCommit setting effects nothing in this case. Both stmts will be executed. Second query will overwrite the data state obtained after first query execution.

Comment: Moreover, if you'll set AutoCommit to TRUE and remove Commit then you'll obtain the same final result always. No difference to you. But there is difference for parallel processes. With AutoCommit=FALSE they'll see the result of 1st stmt after Commit only whereas with TRUE - immediately after 1st stmt execution.

Answer (score 0):

In short - both queries will be executed as a single atomic operation when auto commit is false and you are only committing at the end. This will happen in the order you issues them usually but can depend on which database you are using.

That should be fairly easy to verify if you run the code commenting the operations or updating the same record with both queries.

Answer (score -2):

```
Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
Connection con = ... // create the connection
con.setAutoCommit(false);
return con;
```

}

setAutoCommit(false) call here so that callers of this method never have to worry about setting it.

Comment: Please share more details. How does this answer the given question whether both queries are executed or not?